# How to speed up method 'fit' in custom DecisionTreeClassifier by using NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm doing my homework on implementing the decision tree classifier, the problem is that my algorithm works, and it produces a result no worse in accuracy than the tree from the sklearn library, but it works much-much longer. I checked both of them on the dataset "wine" and mine works for 300ms compared to sklearn which works for 1.5 ms, please, tell me how I should rewrite the code below using only the numpy library, without connecting to GPUs or something like that.

```
def __info(self, x, y, criterion):
    """
    Считаем меру неопределённости
    посредством критерия criterion
    по выборке (x, y)
    """
    y_len = y.shape[0]
    if y_len == 0:
        return 0.0

    prob_distr = np.bincount(y,\
                             minlength=self.num_class,\
                             weights=[1/y_len]*y_len)

    if   criterion == 'error':
        return 1 - prob_distr.max()

    elif criterion == 'gini':
        return 1 - np.power(prob_distr, 2).sum()

    elif criterion == 'entropy':
        return -(prob_distr * np.log2(prob_distr+1e-10)).sum() # 2 - в битах (e - натах).

    else:
        return 0.1
        # raise RuntimeError("No such criterion as \'{}\'!".format(criterion))


def __find_threshold(self, x, y):
    """
    Находим оптимальный признак и порог для сплита
    Здесь используемые разные impurity в зависимости от self.criterion
    """
    max_info_gain = -1
    if x.shape[0] == 0:
        raise RuntimeError("Received an empty sample!")

    for feature_id in range(x.shape[1]): # Использовать np.apply_along_axis()

        current_info = self.__info(x, y, self.criterion)

        tmp = np.unique(x[:,feature_id])
        if tmp.shape[0] < 2:
            thresholds = tmp
        else:
            thresholds = np.mean((tmp[:-1], np.roll(tmp, -1)[:-1]), axis=0)

        for threshold in thresholds: # Испо-ать np.apply_along_axis()

            x_left, x_right, y_left, y_right = self.__div_samples(x, y, feature_id, threshold)
            left_share = x_left.shape[0] / x.shape[0]

            left_info  = left_share       * self.__info(x_left,  y_left,  self.criterion)
            right_info = (1 - left_share) * self.__info(x_right, y_right, self.criterion)

            info_gain = current_info - left_info - right_info

            if info_gain > max_info_gain:

                max_info_gain = info_gain
                best_feature_id = feature_id
                best_threshold  = threshold


    x_left, x_right, y_left, y_right = self.__div_samples(x, y, best_feature_id, best_threshold) # ~о-мально!
    return best_feature_id, best_threshold, x_left, x_right, y_left, y_right
```

If you want to, you can see full code in my github: https://github.com/DaveMSU/msu_ml_spring_2020/blob/master/03/d.harazyan_hw3.ipynb

Sorry, all comments there in russian)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a GPU with CUDA all setup? then you can use CuPy which uses NumPy but performs all the calculations on the GPU. This often leads to a 10x performance increase. Sure, setting up CUDA is a world of pain (especially if you have old hardware) but CUDA is popular and is **really** efficient and fast...

This is a link to help you get started:-

https://towardsdatascience.com/heres-how-to-use-cupy-to-make-numpy-700x-faster-4b920dda1f56

Comment: Thanks, by the way, i'll go throw the link, but i think it's something like cheat) Actually, i need to transfer calculations from loops to numpy without additional tricks such as using the GPU, because the reviewer will not appreciate this:(

Comment: You can't argue if you utilize all resources of a computer. Unless you are planning to run this code on an abacus, I think the reviewer would be impressed. Sci-kit has invested a LOT of money in their code. To approach their performance, think smart...